# Django: Attach custom field options for specifying external representation

Tags: python, django, django-models

I would like to add some custom field option to fields of Django models, since I'm building an application that will be used with models that only follow a general scheme. The idea is that the app should still work with newly defined models and that all the configuration should happen directly in `models.py`. Therefore I would like to pass some options as keyword arguments, e.g. defining whether the field should show up in an external representation. The problem is that just passing new keyword arguments raises the error of unexpected keyword arguments. So far I have resorted to something like this, which I think is kind of ugly:

```
class CustomCharField(models.CharField):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.custom_option = kwargs['custom_option']
        del kwargs['custom_option']
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

Would there be a cleaner solution?

Furthermore I wonder whether this approach is right at all or if there is a different preferred way to encode an external representation of a model in Django, something like [marshmallow](https://flask-marshmallow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) for Flask.

Comment: @Jamo Really depends on what you are trying to do.Could you explain what you are trying to do?

Comment: @zEro I build a system for storing experimental data. The system should integrate the data based on selected experiments, i.e. merge them in one big table. So depending on what kind of experiments are stored in the versions of the app, there will be different "datatypes", i.e. different models for the experimental data. So I need a way  to say: "Show this column in the result table." and "This is only some unimportant measurement value that is just stored for completeness."  Hope this makes it a little bit clearer.

Comment: Hmm.. I'm still unable to understand fully, but getting close(I think). So the `self.custom_option` you stored will be used to figure out how or what to display in a view right?

Comment: Exactly, I basically need to extend the Django options to do more introspection of the models and fields. E.g. like `self.show=True` would mean include this column in the resulting table were everything is joined together. I need this options to create raw SQL since the ORM seems not so useful if I'm just joining tables.

Comment: Woah! That's a pretty big accusation on ORMs. If you post a specific problem you're facing with joins, we can help you with that. What you're trying to do, is absolutely (I believe) not the right way to do it. Either you handle your views differently in forms (using custom FormField) or use model methods to show what you want to show where you want to show.

Comment: eg. `{{ obj.show_field_x }}` in a template is correct usage even when `show_field_x` is a method on the model.  Remember that model must contain data only (as much as possible), a few helper functions like the one above are fine though.

Comment: Ok, maybe I haven't yet completely fathomed the power of the ORM. But indeed I'm displaying  a table that is generated by a SQL join that can be about 100 lines long, involves a lot of LEFT and FULL OUTER JOINs and I want to display exactly the table that is generated by this SQL query. So I do not really see where the ORM would help me here.

Answer (score 0):

Irrespective of whether the approach is right here is my solution for attaching custom keyword arguments to all Django `Field` classes. The custom options can be specified in a `dict` with variable names as `keys` defaults as `values`.

```
from django.db.models import fields

# Get a dictionay of all field classes.
plain_fields = dict([(name, cls) for name, cls 
                    in fields.__dict__.items() 
                    if type(cls) == type and 
                    issubclass(cls, fields.Field) and 
                    cls != fields.Field])

def options_factory(options):
    """
    Produces a class that allows defining keyword arguments as 
    a mixin on another class.

    Args:
        options (dict): Name of the keyword arguments mapped to their 
            default value.
    """
    class OptionsMixin():

        def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):

            for name, default in options.items():
                self.__dict__[name] = kwargs.pop(name, default)
            super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    return OptionsMixin

# Specify custom options with default values.
customoptions = {'supercooloption': 47,
                 'superfluous_option': None}

CustomOptions = options_factory(customoptions)

# Iterate over the field classes and mix the CustomOptions in.
optionfields = {}
for name, cls in plain_fields.items():
    optionfields[name] = type(name, (CustomOptions, cls), {})

# Update the modules __dict__ so the classes can be imported.
globals().update(optionfields)
```

I specified this in a separate file like `optionmodels.py` in `models.py` in can then be imported like `import myapp.optionmodels as omodels` which allows to use the custom fields with only slight syntax change in comparison to the standard Django fields.

Note that relationship fields like `ManyToManyField` have a different `__init__` signature and therefore would need a different mixin that calls `super().__init__(to, *args, **kwargs)`.